# SyntaxError when trying to create backend project with NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, monorepo

When I'm trying to create a backend project for my angular application in my mono repo, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ycrbo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@nestjs\cli\node_modules\glob\node_modules\minimatch\dist\cjs\index.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
```

I tried creating the project with the strict flag too, as described in the nestjs documentation, but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried uninstalling, and reinstalling nest globally, and I did the same for node too.

Comment: Could you provide command which you're using to create project?